# Googling "Time in [location]" does not work when logged in

Tags: google-search

Normally, googling "Time in Paris" or "Time in California" will output the local time at the given location in a small box, like so:

[image: Tume in location when not logged in]

However, for me, this only work when I'm not logged in. As soon as I log in on my Google account, this type of search no longer works:

[image: Time in location when logged in]

Why?

Comment: Works for me. Does your account indicate you're in a country besides the U.S.?

Comment: It probably does. Why?

Comment: A lot of Google features aren't available in all countries. Based on the menus I see in your screen shots, I'll bet you started at `google.com`, but when you logged in, you were redirected to `google.de`, and that domain doesn't have the feature.

Comment: After logging in, go to `google.com/ncr` (**n**o **c**ountry **r**edirect) and see if "time in [location]" works.

Comment: Aha, I suspected something like that. I tried the /ncr, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: That advice might be outdated.

Comment: In any event, noting that you're redirected to your country-specific Google domain after login is important information to include in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out not to be an issue of country or domain, but an issue of language: my Google was set up in Norwegian (as can be seen on the screen). Switching it back to English (or other supported languages) fixed the issue.

**Changing the language**

[image: Language settings]

[image: Language settings]

**Result**

[image: Success]